# group_by does not summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having a hard time working with the dplyr library. I have been trying to implement a relatively easy piece of code but for some reason when I group by one variable and try to sum to get the total for that variable I get only NA values. Here are my files:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zhxfj6cm6gru0t1/AAA-DgeTrngJ0md12W2bEzi0a

And this is code:

```
library (dplyr)
#we set the working directory
setwd("~/asado/R/emp")
##we list the files
list.files()
##we load the csv files
emp1 <- read.csv("AI_EMP_CT_A.csv", sep=',')
##emp1 contains employment information for US counties with naics classification
##empva is another part of the same dataset
empva <- read.csv("AI_EMP_CT_VA_A.csv", sep=',')
##we merge our files, they have the same dimentions so rbind works
emp <- data.frame(rbind(emp1, empva))
##we create a variable to summarize our data
##and make sure is stored as character
emp$naics <- as.character(substring(emp$Mnemonic,3,6))

##we try to summarize by the variable naics, summing for Dec.2013
useemp<- emp%.% group_by(naics) %.%
  summarize(total=sum(Dec.2013, na.rm=T))
##the resulting dataframe shows NA
head(useemp)
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: It's `na.rm` not `rm.na`.

Comment: I didn't test your data, but try two things: update `dplyr` to the latest version (where %>% replaced %.% although I can still be used) and use `dplyr::summarize(total=sum(Dec.2013, na.rm=T))` to make sure you're not in conflict with `plyr`. Does that change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, but it was complicated to read your empva file because the last column, 
the Dec.2013 was filled of `;` and not separated from it. Are you sure it is read as numeric?

```
useemp <- emp %>% group_by(naics) %>%
      summarize(total=sum(Dec.2013, na.rm=T))
    head(useemp)

    Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

      naics     total
    1  2111 132.04674
    2  2121  24.84666
    3  2122  23.90470
    4  2123  17.57697
    5  2131  77.20557
    6  2211 119.30697
```

Comment: They are asking about dplyr, not plyr.

Comment: Joran, the reason why I am using dplyr is that plyr will take forever. The file I uploaded is just a sample of the original file with a million observations and variables.

Comment: Yes the Dec.2013 works as numeric, I think using %.% rather than %>% was the problem. Thanks.